# Can monsters steal items and omens

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If a monster beats a hero in a battle with more than 2 physical damage, can they steal some of their items/omens? And what will the monster do with them, if they can do that, can they use them normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless the specific haunt says otherwise, monsters can never carry items.

From [the rulebook](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/BetrayalAtTheHouseOnTheHill-rules.pdf) (first edition quote; though this did not change between editions):

> Monsters can’t carry items (unless the haunt says
>   otherwise).

Comment: Thanks! What about the traitor, because actually I wanted to ask about him. Can he steal items in battles? Is the traitor a monster, or he only controls monsters?

Comment: The traitor is not a monster in any way; he continues to act like a regular explorer including having items and stealing. The only difference with a traitor is that damaging rooms no longer hurt him.